# Calling a PHP class variable with a variable

Tags: php

I have a PHP class definition that uses a class called databaseObject for all typical database methods (Crud, Etc). I recently changed my database structure so that the id columns in each table are no longer called "id" and are now whatever the table holds + id (For example: Companies Table has an id of "companyId"). So now in my classes that extend databaseObject I include a static variable called $table_id that holds the name of the id for that table. I have run into a situation when now I need to call for that class variable. Example code is below. This code is being run in PHP 5.3.

```
//databaseObject Delete Method;
public function delete() {
    global $database;
    //DELETE FROM table WHERE condition LIMIT 1
    //escape all values to prevent SQL injection
    // - use LIMIT 1
    $sql  = "DELETE FROM ".static::$table_name;
    $sql .= " WHERE ".static::$table_id."=". $database->escape_value($this->id);
    $sql .= " LIMIT 1"; 
    $database->query($sql);
    return ($database->affected_rows() ==1) ? true : false;
}

//Actual Class that creates the issue
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'database.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'databaseobject.php');

class Contact extends DatabaseObject {
    protected static $table_name="contacts";
    protected static $table_id="contactId";
    protected static $db_fields = array('contactId','companyId','contactName', 'phone', 'fax', 'email');
    public $contactId;
    public $companyId;
    public $contactName;
    public $phone;
    public $fax;
    public $email;
}

//Code that calls the method
$contact = Contact::find_by_id($_GET['contactId']);
if($contact && $contact->delete()) {
    $session->message("The Contact was deleted.");
    log_action('Contact Deleted', "Contact was deleted by User ID {$session->id}");
    redirect_to("../companies/viewCompany.php?companyId={$contact->companyId}");    
} else {
    $session->message("The Contact could not be deleted");
    redirect_to('../companies/listCompanies.php');
```

}

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. He already had static members, so I figure he already knows how to work with them. I bet that now he's asking how to access the class field which bares the name which is in $table_id. That would make sense.

Answer (score 3):

Use `self::$variable` not `static::$variable`

Comment: why? Please read the documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php and respond, WHY is static:: incorrect in this case?

Answer (score -2):

What you need is [Reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.getvalue.php)

```
class Foo {
    protected $bar = 'barrr!';
    private $baz = 'bazzz!';
}

$reflFoo = new ReflectionClass('Foo');
$reflBar = $reflFoo->getProperty('bar');
$reflBaz = $reflFoo->getProperty('baz');

// Set private and protected members accessible for getValue/setValue
$reflBar->setAccessible(true);
$reflBaz->setAccessible(true);

$foo = new Foo();
echo $reflBar->getValue($foo); // will output "barrr!"
echo $reflBaz->getValue($foo); // will output "bazzz!"

// You can also setValue
$reflBar->setValue($foo, "new value");
echo $reflBar->getValue($foo); // will output "new value"
```

you access the Field Name by `Contract::$table_id` and get the value `contractId`. So if I understand correctly, you want to get `$contract->contractId`, but the name, `contractId` is determined by a code executed prior to this.

This is where reflection comes in handy.